do-while using || or && in c#
I'm learing C# with microsoft website . When doing do-while practice from the website, I tried to use || for while condition. But it didn't work properly.
int heroLife = 10;
int monsterLife = 10;
int round = 1;

do
{
  int attackPoint = new Random().Next(1,10);
  if(round%2 != 0)
  {
    monsterLife -= attackPoint;
    Console.WriteLine($"Monster was damaged and lost {attackPoint} health and now has {monsterLife} health.");
  }
  else
  {
    heroLife -= attackPoint;
    Console.WriteLine($"Hero was damaged and lost {attackPoint} health and now has {heroLife} health.");
    
  }
  round++;
}while(heroLife<=0 || monsterLife<=0);

Console.WriteLine(heroLife > 0 ? "Hero wins!" : "Monster wins!");

The code only run one time, even if heroLife and monsterLife are bigger than 0. It will work if I change while(heroLife<=0 || monsterLife<=0) to while(heroLife>0 && monsterLife>0);.
Did I misunderstanding || ? Or just don't use || in while condition?

It repeats if heroLife<=0 || monsterLife<=0, which means it won't repeat if the heroLife or monsterLife is bigger than 0. It is "do while" not "do until"

while (x <= 0 || y <= 0)- will run if x is less than or equal to zero, or y is less than equal to zero. For a do/while loop such as yours, the condition will be evaluated before each time the loop returns to the top.while (x > 0 && y > 0)will repeat if both x and y are greater than 0.||is a short-circuiting loigcal OR, and&&` is a short-circuiting logical AND.

why are you creating a new Random() every iteration? Just create one instance and reuse it

@qrsngky yeah you're right, I  misunderstood do while. Thank you!

@phuclv thanks for code review! Didn't notice that, I'll change my code.

You are confusing two concepts: while and the logical AND/OR (&&/||) behaviors. while is a looping structure which translates to "While this condition is true, loop" So when you tell it "while Hero life <= 0 OR Monster life <= 0" you should understand that it will never loop unless the hero landed the perfect hit on the first iteration.
What you were probably looking for was effectively "until either Hero OR Monster is dead". The issue isn't the "OR", it is "until" rather than "while". Another way to phrase this is "while both Hero AND Monster are alive", which is exactly why while(heroLife > 0 && monsterLife > 0) works as you expect.  "OR" doesn't really suit any "while true" scenario. If we use something like while(heroLife > 0 || monsterLife > 0) the loop would run until both Hero and Monster were dead. Changing the logical operation or inverting the comparisons cannot change the behaviour of a "while true" into an "until true". Performing an "until" check can be done by having a break condition inside of a loop. (Not recommended over a properly structured loop condition)
As mentioned in the comments, you also should avoid putting the Random declaration inside of the loop. Random is a simple quasi-random generator and is very timing sensitive so putting it in a loop can result in getting particularly similar values out of it. You only need to initialize it before entering the loop then call the Next() method inside the loop. The resulting code would look like:
int heroLife = 10;
int monsterLife = 10;
int round = 1;
Random random = new Random();

do
{
  int attackPoint = random.Next(1,10);
  if(round % 2 != 0)
  {
    monsterLife -= attackPoint;
    Console.WriteLine($"Monster was damaged and lost {attackPoint} health and now has {monsterLife} health.");
  }
  else
  {
    heroLife -= attackPoint;
    Console.WriteLine($"Hero was damaged and lost {attackPoint} health and now has {heroLife} health.");
  }
  round++;
} while(heroLife > 0 && monsterLife > 0);

Console.WriteLine(heroLife > 0 ? "Hero wins!" : "Monster wins!");


Got it! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!
